# Parametrize set of tests using PyTest

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest

I have the following problem, I need to execute a bunch of tests using [pytest](http://pytest.org/latest/) which each test is basically the same, the only difference is the parameter.

For instance I have to execute:

```
  ./command_line arg1
  ./command_line arg2
  ...
  ./command_line argN
```

And then I need to verify that the executable *command* always returns an expected given result.

I am aware of [this](http://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html#fixture), so I would like to ask for a piece of advice about which would be the best approach for my problem.

I thank you in advance!

Edit:
Finally I found the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765235/simplest-way-of-parameterizing-tests-in-python?rq=1) in StackOverflow where is adviced to take a look to [this page](http://blog.devork.be/2008/09/generative-tests.html) which I found useful in my case.

Comment: Generating tests using `yield` as described in the blog post you link too (which I wrote) is no longer recommended (it was written in 2008!).  The answer provided by @sashk below is the way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually do this using `pytest.mark.parametrize` and it works like this:

```
import pytest


@pytest.mark.parametrize('arg, result', [
 ('arg1', 'result1'),
 ('arg2', 'result2'),
 ('arg3', 'result3'),
 ('argN', 'resultN'),
])
def test_cmd0(arg, result):
    out = subprocess.check_output(['cmd', arg])
    assert out.rstrip() == out
```

where `arg1`, .. `argN` - your arguments, and `result1`, .., `resultN` your expected results.

In example above, I showed how to launch external command and expect different result on every run. If expected result is same, you can always skip `result` in parametrization and just do:

```
assert out.rstrip() == 'expected result'
```

Comment: Even if I already solved my problem using the link I added in my edit I am going to choose the @sashk's answer because I understand it also solves the problem I posed.